# Is my syntax correct?

Tags: syntax, lua, syntax-error

Could someone tell me if they see any syntax erros, I do not know lua and I am trying to make a small edit to an addon I use. If my syntax is incorrect could you please show me how to correct it and if it is correct could you please confirm that it is correct.

```
if(name) then
    if(name == "SomebodiesName") then
        name = name .. " (Udders! someone pop a gbank =)";
    end
end
```

Error I recieve when trying to run the addon with this code added to it:

```
Message: REDACTED.lua:411: attempt to call field 'GT' (a nil value)
Count: 1
Stack: REDACTED.lua:411: in function <REDACTED.lua:410>

Locals: self = BuffCheck_MinimapButton {
 0 = <userdata>
}
(*temporary) = nil
(*temporary) = "attempt to call field 'GT' (a nil value)"
```

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error when you try to run it?

Comment: Yes, we are not your interpreter/compiler :-) What did your _actual_ intepreter/compiler say?

Comment: I am getting a null error of some sort and this is the only code that I added. Since it checks if name is null before it continues I concluded I must be doing something wrong somewhere within this block.

Comment: @paxdiablo I am not using one, just a simple text editor. The addon is for a game and when it does not function the game throws errors. I will add the errors I recieve when trying to run this code above.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the code you posted. What's in line 411? Apparently there's no GT field in whatever structure you are accessing

Comment: FWIW there is no need (but also no problem) to put parenthesis around the condition for an `if` statement, e.g. `if name then` is valid and idiomatic. Also, a semi-colon is never needed in Lua, and it is also idiomatic not to have them.

Comment: It would help to see the original addon code around your code showing the edit you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the code snippet you've shown looks okay, according to [CodingGround](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm), which is an excellent site to visit <sup>(a)</sup> if you need to check something quickly but you don't have a particular development environment just lying around.

```
name = "x";
if(name) then
    if(name == "x") then
        name = name .. " (Udders! someone pop a gbank =)";
    end
end;
print(name);
```

That outputs:

```
x (Udders! someone pop a gbank =)
```

(whatever *that* means).

Given that the error seems to be about calling a field `'GT'` which is set to `nil` and nowhere in your code snippet, I would suggest the problem lies *elsewhere.*

---

<sup>(a)</sup> My *other* favorites are [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).